# My code in VBA is throwing index out of bounds but I'm sure the array is the right length

Tags: excel, vba, indexoutofboundsexception

I need to set `val1` and `val2` to the number assigned to the variable `total`. No matter what I change the variable `total` to, 0-8, it says that the index is out of bounds. I have also printed the length of each of the lists I am referencing with MsgBox and it says 8.

I have tried changing the index to anywhere in this range, and again, still throws errors.

```vb
Sub dataValidation()
    Dim totalFraud As Range
    Dim leftTheBank As Range
    Dim stopped As Range
    Dim totalFraudCells As Variant
    Dim leftTheBankCells As Variant
    Dim stoppedCells As Variant
    Dim fraudCell As Variant
    Dim leftCell As Variant
    Dim stopCell As Variant
    Dim total As Integer
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
    ws.Select

    Set totalFraud = ws.Range("TotalFraud")
    Set leftTheBank = ws.Range("LeftBank")
    Set stopped = ws.Range("Stopped")

    totalFraudCells = totalFraud.Value
    leftTheBankCells = leftTheBank.Value
    stoppedCells = stopped.Value

    total = 0

    For Count = 0 To UBound(totalFraudCells) - LBound(totalFraudCells) + 1
        Dim sum As Integer
        Dim val1 As Integer
        Dim val2 As Integer
    
        val1 = leftTheBankCells(3)
        val2 = stoppedCells(3)
    
        sum = val1 + val2
    
        total = total + 1 
    Next
End Sub
```

I would expect in this case for `val1` and `val2` to be set to the index of the array that is 0, which should both be an integer.

Comment: You're dealing with 2-d arrays here, not 1-d arrays.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> For Count = 0 To UBound(totalFraudCells) - LBound(totalFraudCells) + 1
> ```

You're assuming the lower bound is `0`.

> ```
> Dim totalFraud As Range
> ...
> totalFraudCells = totalFraud.Value
> ```

But `totalFraudCells` is a 1-based, 2D variant array.

Ditto for these:

> ```
> val1 = leftTheBankCells(3)
> val2 = stoppedCells(3)
> ```

If you *know* or otherwise expect to be dealing with single-dimensional arrays, you can use `Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose` to make them so:

```
totalFraudCells = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(totalFraud.Value)
leftTheBankCells = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(leftTheBank.Value)
stoppedCells = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(stopped.Value)
```

Now you're looking at single-dimensional arrays, but they're still one-based.

Rule of thumb, don't assume what the base of an array will be. Use `LBound` to compute the lower bound of your `For` loop:

```
For Count = LBound(totalFraudCells) To UBound(totalFraudCells)
```

And with that every single value of `Count` will be in range for the `totalFraudCells` array.

---

If you are *not* dealing with single-column ranges, then you *must* deal with the 2D nature of the variant arrays; `LBound` and `UBound` can take a second parameter for which dimension you want the lower or upper boundary for:

```
For Count = LBound(totalFraudCells, 1) To UBound(totalFraudCells, 1)
```

If you need to iterate all rows *and columns*, you'll need nested loops, with the inner loop iterating `LBound(totalFraudCells, 2) To UBound(totalFraudCells, 2)` for every subscript in the first dimension.